# Find the segment measure in the triangle below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: In the figure below, $ABC$ is a triangle of heights $AD$, $BE$ and $CF$ respectively. Calculate $DF$ knowing that $BD = 3 cm$, $DC = 8 cm$ and $DE = 6 cm$. $CF$,  $BE$ e $AD$ are perpendicular.(Answer:$4$)
[image]

My progress:
$\triangle DEF$ $ is a orthic triangle

Similarities I found
$\triangle ABD \sim CBF\sim CHD\\
\triangle AEH \sim \triangle BDH \sim\triangle BEC\\
\triangle AEB \sim AFC\\
\frac{CH}{AB}=\frac{HD}{3}=\frac{8}{AD}\\
\frac{11}{AB}=\frac{BF}{3}=\frac{CE}{AD}\\
\frac{11}{CH}=\frac{BF}{DH}=\frac{CF}{8}\\
\frac{11}{BH}=\frac{EC}{HD}=\frac{BE}{3}\\
$

but can't find the relationship with DF...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let O be the intersection of the heights. Let $\angle OBC=\alpha$ and $\angle OCD = \theta$. With the properties of a cyclic quadrilateral, you can find the angles marked in the diagram below in terms of $\alpha$ and $\theta$

[image]

Now observe $\triangle FDC$ and $\triangle BDE$ They're similar!.

With triangle similarity, you can get the following relationship.

$\frac{x}{3}=\frac{8}{6}$.

By simplifying,

$\boxed{x=4}$